# SMS receive format in phones

Tags: android, mobile, sms, internal

Not in smartphones, but in any ordinary mobiles, how is SMS received? What is the format of the message, as in packet format. Is it OS specific? If so, can you please tell me the format in Android mobiles.

Is it possible to trigger a mobile application(like temple-run installed in the mobile) by just receiving the SMS?

Answer (score 0):

This link describes the SMS PDU format: http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/

It is possible to implement an application that can be triggered by SMS.  However, you cannot trigger any arbitrary application to launch just by an SMS being received.

Comment: Is there any format specific to OS? Especially in Android mobiles, how the SMS are interpreted?

Comment: @elevine : Forgive my ignorance as I do not have a lot of knowledge about this, but why can't we have a BroadcastListener which gets triggered whenever a SMS is received and it would start the application that we want it to start on sms receive ?

Comment: @swayam You can have a BroadcastReceiver trigger an Activity in your application or one from another app if it is made available (see http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable).  If an app decides to keep its Activities private, then you will not be able to trigger it.

Comment: @elevine : thanks for the reply and the link! So, if there is an app with public activity, then it can be triggered , right ?